# Is it 'bye from now' or 'bye for now'?

Tags: meaning, interjections

I often hear it in the end of the radio programs. Are they saying 'bye from now' or 'bye for now'? Some times they say 'bye from/for me' if there are more than one person.

What do they mean?

Answer (score 1):

They are saying *'bye for now* and *'bye from me*.  The first suggests that the absence may be temporary, while the second suggests the speaker is leaving but the listener and others may be staying.

The Two Ronnies traditionally ended their show with one saying "It's goodbye from him" and the other saying "and it's goodbye from me".